# Change Title Based on Taxonomy Filter in archive-{cpt}.php

Tags: archives, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

So I have page in Custom Post Type **RENTAL** with following custom taxonomies:

- **Merk** -- with terms: Honda, Daihatsu, Toyota, etc
- **Kendaraan** -- with parent terms: Mobil, Bus, Motor; & child terms: MPV, hatchback, sedan, etc.
- **Seat** -- with terms: 2 seat, 4 seat, 8 seat, etc

**What I Wanted to Achieve**

I want my title H1 in my archive page with taxonomy filter to change based on taxonomy used to filter, example:

```
https://example.com/rental/?kendaraan=mobil&merk=honda&seat=2seat
```

*TITLE*: **Rental Mobil Honda (2 Seat)**

```
https://example.com/rental/?kendaraan=sedan&merk=honda&seat=4seat
```

*TITLE*: **Rental Mobil Sedan Honda (4 Seat)** *(NOTE: "Sedan" being child of "Mobil")*

```
https://example.com/rental/?kendaraan=sedan&merk=honda
```

*TITLE*: **Rental Mobil Sedan Honda** *(NOTE: "Sedan" being child of "Mobil")*

And I also want it to have different title when it has no taxonomy filtered.

```
https://example.com/rental/
```

*TITLE*: **Rental Mobil, Bus, Motor**

Unfortunately my code can achieve 'some' of what I wanted. But the title always pick taxonomy even if it isn't filtered.

```
$merk = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'merk', 'Merk&nbsp;', '', '&nbsp;') );
$kendaraan = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'kendaraan', '', '', '&nbsp;') );
$kendaraanParent = get_term_parents_list( get_the_ID(), 'kendaraan' );
$seat = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'seat_mobil', '(', '', ')' ) );

    <header class="archive-header">
<h1 class="archive-title">
Rental <?php echo $kendaraan ; ?><?php echo $merk ; ?><?php echo $kendaraanParent->name ; ?><?php echo $seat ; ?> - TravelBos.id
</h1>
</header><!-- .archive-header -->
```

Code above works great for when I filter all three taxonomies.

```
https://example.com/rental/?kendaraan=sedan&merk=honda&seat=4seat
```

But when filtering two, one, or none taxonomy(ies) it turned stupid.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this question myself since I found the solution after consulting with my programmer friend.

Basically the code above that I posted is wrong, turns out I shouldn't be using `get_the_term_list` but to use `get_query_var` instead.

The final code is to replace the above code I posted with these code:

EDIT: Change few things to call proper "taxonomy name" as taxonomy slug can be different with taxonomy name. Credit @Milo.

```
<?php
// get the currently queried taxonomy term, for use later in the template file
$kendaraan = get_query_var('kendaraan');
$merk = get_query_var('merk');
$seat = get_query_var('seat');
$kendaraan = get_term_by( 'slug', $kendaraan, 'kendaraan' );
$merk = get_term_by( 'slug', $merk, 'merk' );
$seat = get_term_by( 'slug', $seat, 'seat' );
?>

<h1 class="archive-title">Rental 
<?php if ( empty( $kendaraan ) && empty( $merk ) && empty( $seat ) ): ?>
Mobil, Bus, & Motor - TravelBos.id
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $kendaraan->name; ?> <?php echo $merk->name; ?> <?php if (!empty($seat)) {echo "(". $seat->name .")";} ?> - TravelBos.id
<?php endif; ?>
</h1>
```

Now this code will make it possible for the H1 archive heading to change based on the taxonomy being filtered when viewing that particular archive page.

Hope it helps anyone who has the same problem as me.

Comment: What if the term name isn’t the same as the slug? You need to get the term object by slug, then get the actual name from the term object.

Comment: @Milo can you please elaborate mate so I can edit my code for people which has term name different with their slug. thank you!

Comment: Use [`get_term_by` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) to return the term object from slug. For example, in your code `$kendaraan` contains the slug, so you can use `$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $kendaraan, 'kendaraan' );`, then you can `echo $term->name;` to get the name from the term object.

Comment: @Milo just edit my code to make it get the actual name not the slug. If there are more things to add feel free to tell me. or you can edit the code yourself too.